# VBA. How to find position of first digit in string

Tags: vba, digit

I have string "ololo123".
I need get position of first digit - 1.
How to set mask of search ?

Comment: @Remou thanks, I deleted the remark.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a lightweight and fast method that avoids regex/reference additions, thus helping with overhead and transportability should that be an advantage.

```
Public Function GetNumLoc(xValue As String) As Integer

For GetNumLoc = 1 To Len(xValue)
    If Mid(xValue, GetNumLoc, 1) Like "#" Then Exit Function
Next

GetNumLoc = 0

End Function
```

Answer (score 9):

Something like this should do the trick for you:

```
Public Function GetPositionOfFirstNumericCharacter(ByVal s As String) As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Dim currentCharacter As String
        currentCharacter = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(currentCharacter) = True Then
            GetPositionOfFirstNumericCharacter = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

You can then call it like this:

```
Dim iPosition as Integer
iPosition = GetPositionOfFirstNumericCharacter("ololo123")
```

Comment: You can simplify the function. You don't really need `currentCharacter`; your test could be `If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then...`

Comment: @e100 - very true. Breaking it down makes it more readable and that's what I am for when answering a question of this level of complexity as I work on the basis that the OP may need simpler/clearer code to aid understanding =)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on your environment, but this worked in Excel 2010

```
'Added reference for Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Const myString As String = "ololo123"
Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim regmatch As MatchCollection

regex.Pattern = "\d"
Set regmatch = regex.Execute(myString)
MsgBox (regmatch.Item(0).FirstIndex)   ' Outputs 5
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually have that function:

```
Public Function GetNumericPosition(ByVal s As String) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ii As Integer

    result = -1
    ii = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To ii
        If IsNumeric(Mid$(s, i, 1)) Then
            result = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetNumericPosition = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try regex, and then you'd have two problems. My VBAfu is not up to snuff, but I'll give it a go:

```
Function FirstDigit(strData As String) As Integer
    Dim RE As Object REMatches As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .Pattern = "[0-9]"
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
    FirstDigit = REMatches(0).FirstIndex
End Function
```

Then you just call it with `FirstDigit("ololo123")`.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is an issue, this will run a bit faster than Robs (noi Rob):

```
Public Sub Example()
    Const myString As String = "ololo123"
    Dim position As Long
    position = GetFirstNumeric(myString)
    If position > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Found numeric at postion " & position & "."
    Else
        MsgBox "Numeric not found."
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetFirstNumeric(ByVal value As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim bytValue() As Byte
    Dim lngRtnVal As Long
    bytValue = value
    For i = 0 To UBound(bytValue) Step 2
        Select Case bytValue(i)
            Case vbKey0 To vbKey9
                If bytValue(i + 1) = 0 Then
                    lngRtnVal = (i \ 2) + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
        End Select
    Next
    GetFirstNumeric = lngRtnVal
End Function
```

Comment: so you turn the string to byte and check it by two-byte chunks if the first byte is 0-9 and the second is 0.
but how does that make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

An improved version of spere's answer (can't edit his answer), which works for any pattern

```
Private Function GetNumLoc(textValue As String, pattern As String) As Integer
    For GetNumLoc = 1 To (Len(textValue) - Len(pattern) + 1)
        If Mid(textValue, GetNumLoc, Len(pattern)) Like pattern Then Exit Function
    Next

    GetNumLoc = 0
End Function
```

To **get the pattern value** you can use this:

```
Private Function GetTextByPattern(textValue As String, pattern As String) As String
    Dim NumLoc As Integer
    For NumLoc = 1 To (Len(textValue) - Len(pattern) + 1)
        If Mid(textValue, NumLoc, Len(pattern)) Like pattern Then
            GetTextByPattern = Mid(textValue, NumLoc, Len(pattern))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next    

    GetTextByPattern = ""
End Function
```

Example use:

```
dim bill as String
bill = "BILLNUMBER 2202/1132/1 PT2200136"

Debug.Print GetNumLoc(bill , "PT#######")
'Printed result:
'24

Debug.Print GetTextByPattern(bill , "PT#######")
'Printed result:
'PT2200136
```